# DPAD Navigation glitchy with ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to make an app for TV. The app has two listViews, and then some textViews below. The listViews are populate with around 5 items each. When the app starts the user should be able to switch between the listViews using the LEFT and RIGHT directional buttons, and navigate between items on the listViews using the UP and DOWN buttons. The DPAD_CENTER should initiate the listView items click.

The problem is that the UP and DOWN keys are not working properly. LEFT and RIGHT will do things (I wrote some debug code to show a test message in a TextView when the button is pressed) but the UP and DOWN will only do so every 5th press. The fact that it's every fifth press and the listView has 5 items suggests to me that the first four presses are interacting over the listViews items (which would be fine) but if I check the listView.getSelectedItemPosition it always returns 0.

Any ideas what's going wrong.

CODE (To shortened the code I've removed the section that creates a custom Adapater with an ASYNC task to download the data and populate the list view but I can add that if you think it would help)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextClock;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private ListView listOne;
    private ListView listTwo;
    private TextClock clock;

    RssListViewAdapter adapterOne;
    RssListViewAdapter adapterTwo;


    private TextView focusView;
    private TextView listItem;
    private RelativeLayout master;

    private int position;
    private int leftorright;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rss_layout);

        //STUFF THAT CALLS CUSTOM ADAPATER WITH ASYNC TASK TO LOAD CONTENT INTO 
        //LISTVIEWS

        focusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.focusMove);
        listItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        listOne.setFocusable(true);
        listOne.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        listOne.requestFocus();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        boolean handled = false;

        switch (keyCode){
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                listItem.setText(Integer.toString(listOne.getSelectedItemPosition()));
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                //listOne.setSelection(position);
                int i = listOne.getSelectedItemPosition();
                listOne.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null).performClick();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
                listItem.setText("UP");
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                listItem.setText("DOWN");
                break;

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

As the system was capturing the UP and DOWN key presses I needed to use `dispatchKeyEvent()` rather than `onKeyDown()`.